# PyQGIS handle ##output=html as input of geoprocessing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, html, interface

In QGIS 2.14.5 I would like to create a model that determines a statistics for a raster layers' unique values (Tool `Raster layer statistics`) and does some further computations with the result.

I think, the output of this tool must be `##output=html`, according to the documentation http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/de/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html?highlight=script.

The question is, when writing a geoprocessing script that computes this `html` output, what is the corresponding `input`?

Since there is no `##input=html`, I tried `##input=file` and `##input=longstring` as well, but I'am not able to connect the output of the above mentioned tool to my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `output html` parameter is only used to display information as it seems to just read the data which you can see from the script: [RasterLayerStatistics.py](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/RasterLayerStatistics.py).

You could create a **custom script** and apply a similar method as in the script by taking the relevant statistical values directly from the raster and apply further calculations. I tend to use something like:

```
##Example=name
##Layer=raster

from qgis.core import QgsRasterBandStats

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
provider = layer.dataProvider()
ext = layer.extent()
stats = provider.bandStatistics(1,QgsRasterBandStats.All,ext,0)

valid_cells = stats.elementCount
nodata_cells = stats.None
minimum_value = stats.minimumValue
maximum_value = stats.maximumValue
sum = stats.sum
mean = stats.mean
std_dev = stats.stdDev

# Print above statistics or use them as input for calculations
print "Valid cells: ", valid_cells
print "No-data cells:", nodata_cells
print "Minimum value: ", minimum_value
print "Maximum value: ", maximum_value
print "Sum: ", sum
print "Mean value: ", mean
print "Standard deviation: ", std_dev
```